# Recursive function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var DynamicModelView = {          
    createModelView: function (obj,vitalslength,headerValue) {     
      for(vitalsCount = 0, vitalsLen = vitalslength; vitalsCount < vitalsLen; vitalsCount++) {
              // Business logic... with obj and headerValue

       }       

      I need to call this function again.    
      When i call `this.createModelView(arguements)` it keeps on executing... 
    }            
}
```

I need execute the function based on the count... the for loop executes perfectly based on the count, but the function executes only once.

Comment: your description is a bit vague... how do you call that function? what do you mean it keeps on executing? the meaning of the recursion is that a function keeps on executing while a condition is active. What's your exit case? when you call that function, what do you mean by "arguments"? if you keep passing the same arguments, the function will keep on executing...

Comment: If you are calling it from inside itself, you must have a condition somewhere that stops the recursion. Otherwise, it will endlessly call itself.

Comment: What is the "obj" parameter? ... But mostly, do you know how to use `this`? Call `DynamicModelView.createModelView(...)` if you want to program functionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle recursive looping (anyone else remember SICP here? Ah... blessed Scheme).

```
createModelView: function (obj,vitalslength,headerValue) {     
  for(vitalsCount = 0, vitalsLen = vitalslength; 
          vitalsCount < vitalsLen; vitalsCount++) {
          // Business logic... with obj and headerValue

   }       

  // the following will force this method to keep going with the same parameters
  // unless you put a conditional return statement before it
  // I always use an interim variable so JS can't get confused.
  var args = arguments; 
  // are you sure it's this here and not DynamicModelView.createModelView
  this.createModelView.apply(this, args) 
}
```

More realistically (and faster), you may want to simply put a while loop inside the function:

```
createModelView: function (obj,vitalslength,headerValue) {     
  do {
      for(vitalsCount = 0, vitalsLen = vitalslength; 
             vitalsCount < vitalsLen; vitalsCount++) {
             // Business logic... with obj and headerValue

       }     
  } while( /* condition which needs to be met to finish loop*/ );  
}
```

If you want to make sure that the function only runs x times, then you could do this:

```
// notice the last parameter?
createModelView: function (obj,vitalslength,headerValue, x) {  
  for( var i = 0; i < x; i++ )   
  {
      for(vitalsCount = 0, vitalsLen = vitalslength; 
             vitalsCount < vitalsLen; vitalsCount++) {
             // Business logic... with obj and headerValue

       }     
  }
}
```

Hopefully that can get you started.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a working termination statement in your function. Start your function with a condition which stops your recursion.

```
var DynamicModelView = {          
    createModelView: function (obj,vitalslength,headerValue) {     

       ***if (<stop condition>) return;***

       for(vitalsCount = 0, vitalsLen = vitalslength; vitalsCount < vitalsLen; vitalsCount++) {
              // Business logic... with obj and headerValue

       }       

      I need to call this function again.    
      When i call `this.createModelView(arguements)` it keeps on executing... 
    }            
}
```

Comment: I have serious doubts that the OP even knows *why* he calls the function recursively. It just doesn't add up for me. So telling how to stop the endless recursion is one thing, but I'm pretty positive that recursion is not even what he needs.